# Access denied for S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I was trying to block public access to S3 but enable it from application which is hosted on EC2 instance, and after applying the bucket policy, I got error that I don't have permissions for any actions on that S3 bucket, even I have admin role and I can edit the other S3 buckets.

This is the policy that I have applied

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MyBucketPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2Instances",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ID:role/Role1"          
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAllOtherRequests",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What changes and what permission do I need to apply to my IAM user to be able to do the changes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *DenyAllOtherRequests* is not how IAM works - a Deny overwrites any other Allow. You now need your root user credentials to "unlock" that bucket again. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access

Comment: When you say "enable it from application which is hosted on EC2 instance", how is the application accessing the bucket? Is it using API calls via an AWS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are **private by default**.

To block public access to your S3 bucket but allow applications to use it:

- Do **not** add a Bucket Policy
- Put the required S3 permissions directly on the IAM Role

When your application uses Amazon S3, use an AWS SDK to access S3. Such requests will be authenticated with AWS credentials and are not considered 'public' access.

I would advise against adding `s3:*` permissions to the IAM Role. This grants permissions to do *anything* in Amazon S3, including deleting all data and all the buckets in that AWS account.

Amazon S3 buckets also have a feature called **S3 Block Public Access**. If this feature is activated, then it is not possible to add a Bucket Policy or ACL. This ensures that content is not publicly accessible. The fact that you have added a Bucket Policy suggests that you have deactivated this feature.

If you are currently unable to do anything with that S3 bucket (due to your "Deny Everything" rule), you will need to **use your AWS root account** to remove the bucket policy.